# Javascript - Allow requests only from authorized sites

Tags: javascript

Google Adsense has an authorized sites feature.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65062?hl=en

How did they implement this using just client side includes?

Reason I ask is because I need to authenticate similar requests. My server provides a javascript include. I need to accept requests from certain urls, and not other urls or people running it on localhost.

Usually I would keep a private API key on the server. But in this case, I don't want people to run another script on their server.

The only other way I can think of doing it is to not be 100%, and create an algorithm for matching.

Comment: you should modify the allowed origin in header of the server

Comment: `alert(!!location.origin.match("stackoverflow.com"))` is pretty darn 100%... you can also check the referrer, which is _fairly_ reliable. look into apache redirects, which can hit the referrer.

Comment: Yes, allowed origin will keep unsuspecting users from running it in their browsers. That's good.

What about malicious users downloading it, getting a JWT and running a script?

Comment: @steve76: if i understand you correctly, there's nothing that can prevent that. if the code can be seen, it can be run, and you need a server at least and ideally authentication to control what can be seen by whom. js can run on any page by default, but if you're looking to "hide code", forget about it.

Comment: yep, that's what I thought. it's a ddos problem. I'm also betting adsense makes advertisers put code on their landing page which reports back the referrer.